# The python script doesn't stop

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv and numpy for human body detection using HOGDescriptor.
Here is the code, I am playing with:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
cv2.startWindowThread()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/****/Desktop/people_walk.mkv')
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    boxes, weights = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8) )
    boxes = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in boxes])
    for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in boxes:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB),
                          (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

So after pressing <kbd>q</kbd> the camera window should closed. In fact it does, but the script keeps on running and the whole execution doesn't stop even after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or exit(). Any help with this?

Comment: How about removing the last line of the code above (`cv2.waitKey(1)`)?

Comment: Does it work fine if you replace waitKey(1) with waitKey(1000) ? It's possible that you spend too little time waiting, so the key pressing never comes while you are waiting, but during the other computations in the loop instead. In this case, trying 1000 will work fine, and then you'll just have to find the right value between 1and 1000 so that it works and you don't slow the process down too much...

Comment: Neither removing the waitkey worked nor changing the waitkey value to 1000 worked..

Comment: I think the problem arises due to hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector()) ...because working without it, the window stops and the script execution ends properly...not sure about this, but is there any line i should have that stops the HOG?

Answer (score 0):

It's coming from the while exit condition.

Try this:
Prioritize the bitwise operation and put 33 instead of 1 on the WaitingKey.

```py
if (cv2.waitKey(33) & 0xFF) == ord('q'):
```

Comment: bitwise operation [already has priority over equality check  ](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity)

Comment: didn't work...as i said.. the problem is with the hog descriptor line..because removing those lines and keeping the rest of it as it is, works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was with the line

```
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()   
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
```

had to add the line in the waitkey() if condition

```
  hog.setSVMDetector(None)
```